# localStorage.getItem returns null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to store a variable of my React.js app in the localStorage so that when the user switches between different pages, the app simply checks if there is an entry for a given uuid in the localStorage, and either loads the previous state or initialises the variable (this.props.id gets passed on from the parent component and helps to identify this specific component and its variables in the local memory). This code is located in the constructor of my component.
:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('Value-' + this.props.id) === null) {
  localStorage.setItem('Value-' + this.props.id, JSON.stringify(initialValue);
} else {
  initialValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Value-' + this.props.id)))
}
```

Everything loads fine, the variable is initialised and stored into the localStorage. I then change the variable content through

```
localStorage.setItem('Value-' + this.props.id, JSON.stringify(ModifiedValue);
```

and once again, inspecting the localStorage shows that those changes are correctly reflected in local memory.

However, if i then switch between pages and come back to the page in question, localStorage.getItem('Value-' + this.props.id) returns null. Despite the fact that when i put a break into the code and inspect the localStorage, it shows that the relevant entry is there, and the if statement should not be null.

Any ideas why this is happening? I am aware that storing my variable in the localStorage this way might not be ideal, but that cannot be changed atm. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this code is being run on page change, since you run it in the constructor?

Comment: Hard to help without a [mcve]

Comment: @Tholle Good point, let me check

Comment: @Tholle yes, the constructor runs on page changes.

Comment: @Fesch That's frustrating. [My simple example works](https://codesandbox.io/s/yq8v2zx8qj). Maybe you can see something that differs there?